# Values are undefined on load time

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-services

I'm working on angular app.

In my service file, I created a function `configure`. And it as been called in `AfterViewInit` in an component.

But On load time, `this.config` is undefined, If I use it inside `setTimeOut` I could able to access the `value` of the `this.config`.

The below code works,

```
  configure() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if(this.config) {
        this.apply();
      } 
    }, 200);
  }
```

Is there any better way to do it ? without using setTimeOut.

Please help

Comment: Where and when is `this.config` set?

Comment: I'm not sure, but `this.config` is loaded in the same service file with different function . Since its an big app i'm not able to follow it

Answer (score 0):

try with [markForCheck](https://pub.dev/documentation/angular/latest/angular/ChangeDetectorRef/markForCheck.html) method

```
constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngOnInit(){
{
  this.cdr.markForCheck();
  this.configure()  

}

configure(){

  if(this.config) {
    // your code
  } 

}
```

add the below code to @Component decorator

```
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with below code

```
configure() {
    var self = this;
    setTimeout(() => {
      if(self.config) {
        self.apply();
      } 
    }, 200);
}
```